# Subquery FROM clause SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have problem with writing a sub query in `FROM` clause.

Write a `SELECT` statement that returns three columns:

- `VendorName` (from the Vendors table)
- `LatestInv` (summary function that returns the last entry from InvoiceDate)
- `AverageInv` (summary function that returns the average from InvoiceTotal)

**Hint**: you will need to join two tables before joining to the derived table (the subquery)

**Sub query portion**: `SELECT` statement that returns the top ten `VendorID` and `AverageInv` (same name and function as described in the outer query). Group the results by the appropriate column and sort the results by `AverageInv` from largest to smallest. Correlate the sub query as `BestVendors` and join it to the correct table (where both share a key field).

Group the outer query by the appropriate column and sort the results by LatestInv most recent to oldest."

Code:

```
SELECT 
    VendorName, 
    MAX(InvoiceDate) AS LatestInv, 
    AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS AverageInv
FROM 
    Vendors 
JOIN 
    Invoices ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID
(SELECT TOP 10 
     VendorID,
     AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS AverageInv
 FROM Invoices
 GROUP BY VendorID
 ORDER BY AverageInv DESC) AS BestVendor ON Vendors.VendorID = BestVendor.VendorID
GROUP BY 
    VendorName
ORDER BY 
    LatestInv DESC;
```

This is with what I come so far but is not correct, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Add a JOIN before the subquery:

```
SELECT 
    VendorName, 
    MAX(InvoiceDate) AS LatestInv, 
    AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS AverageInv
FROM 
    Vendors 
JOIN 
    Invoices ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID 
JOIN 
(SELECT TOP 10 
     VendorID,
     AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS AverageInv
 FROM Invoices
 GROUP BY VendorID
 ORDER BY AverageInv DESC) AS BestVendor
    ON Vendors.VendorID = BestVendor.VendorID
GROUP BY 
    VendorName
ORDER BY 
    LatestInv DESC;
```